# AEM - sorting of products

Tags: sorting, aem

See the attached screenshot. The products that have just been added are at the bottom of the list. I need to sort them, to be able to put them on the top of the list, on the first page, first positions. Is there any way to do it without doing it manually? At the moment I need to do it manually, but it's a long and boring process.

Thanks a lot!

[these products that have just been imported, are at the bottom of the list, on the 5th page out of five](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5jlO.png)

Comment: Can you be a little bit more specific? Maybe add a screenshot. I am not sure what you mean by "Product Idents".

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Jens ! I've edited the original question with a screenshot, hope it helps!